# How to update state with data from a find() method based on value passed from a select drop down

Tags: reactjs

I want to populate item category drop down such that when item name is selected from Item name dropdown, the item id is passed to find the current item from a list of items held in state. This is triggered in an onChange event handler called handleSelectedItem. In the handleSelectedItem handler I try to set the state of item to the current item or newItem found, as shown in code my code sample below.

The problem is after I set the state or so it seems and try to map through the item in state to populate the category option list, I get an error "item.map is not a function".

Please help me solve this issue.

I have tried looking up online for similar issues and how to fix but to no avail.

```
class Inventory extends Component {
  state = {
  items: [],
  item: [],
  pagination: {},
  loading: false
};

handleItemSelect = (itemId) => {
  const Items = this.state.items;
  let item = this.state.item;
  let newItem = [];

   newItem = Items.find(itemById => itemById._id === itemId);

   this.setState({
     item: newItem
   });

   console.log(itemId);
   console.log(item);
};

fetchItems = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/items`, { method: "GET" })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(items => {
      // console.log(items, items.length);

      const pagination = { ...this.state.pagination };

      //Read total count from server
      pagination.total = items.length;

      this.setState({ loading: false, items: items, pagination });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchItems();
}

render() {
  const topColResponsiveProps = {
    xs: 24,
    sm: 12,
    md: 12,
    lg: 12,
    xl: 6
  };

  const { items, item } = this.state;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>Inventory - [Receive Stock]</h2>

      <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
        <Column {...topColResponsiveProps}>
          <Card title="Item Details">
            <FormItem label="Item Name:">
              <Select
                showSearch
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                placeholder="Select Item"
                optionFilterProp="children"
                onChange={this.handleItemSelect}
                filterOption={(input, option) =>
                  option.props.children
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                }
              >
                {items.map(item => (
                  <Option key={item._id} value={item._id}>
                    {item.item_name}
                  </Option>
                ))}
            </Select>
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="Category:">
            <Select
              showSearch
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              placeholder="Select category"
              optionFilterProp="children"
              filterOption={(input, option) =>
                option.props.children
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
              }
            >
              {item.map(itemCat => (
                <Option key={itemCat._id}>{itemCat.category_name}</Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormItem>
        </Card>
      </Column>
    </Row>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

I expect to update the value of item:[] in state to the value the newItem, so I can map through to populate the category option list.

Comment: Please show an example of what `items` looks like. I recommend replacing the `fetch` logic with just hard-coding the JSON and putting that in your question text. That gets the API call out of the picture and will allow us to see the exact data structure of `items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect `item` to be an array, and yet you are setting it to be an object ([`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the item in the array, not an array itself):

```
newItem = Items.find(itemById => itemById._id === itemId);

// newItem here is whatever object was returned by `find`

this.setState({
  item: newItem,
});

// this.state.item is now an object, and you can't `.map` an object
```

So, you should either wrap the `newItem` in an array:

```
this.setState({
  item: [newItem],
});
```

Or, since `item` probably shouldn't be an array to begin with since it's just a single item, just don't try to map over it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Matthew, wrapped the newItem in an array and I was able to map through to populate the category drop down. One small issue is that when I first select the item from the list I get an empty array. I have to select a second item to get data in the array

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you’re using find() function which returns the first element that matches itemById._id, so it drops and error, yuo can check making a log of item right on top  inside render function, you should use filter() instead which returns an array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I shall try this and respond back.